# Mouse 8 and 9 (side buttons) only work when pressing another mouse button

Tags: 18.04, mouse, input-devices

My side mouse buttons are mouse 8 and mouse 9. They are for going forward and back in the browser. However, they only work if I am pressing another mouse key before it. So as an example I need to press and hold mouse 1, and then the side buttons work. I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Did you fix the problem? I'm having the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04, please let me know.

Comment: @teaver Yes, it has to do with imwheel. If you have it installed run this command in the terminal and your side buttons should work:

imwheel --kill --buttons "4 5"

If you have a script or added a command to your startup applications for imwheel, change it so imwheel starts with the above command.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue out on this and it has to do with a conflict with imwheel. If you have it installed run the following command and add it to the startup applications so imwheel starts with this command:

imwheel --kill --buttons "4 5"

Answer (score 0):

It was because in my mouse software in windows I had set that that mouse button type 9 and the other one 8 but those numbers for some reason didn't work and it does nothing to had to go and change it to default again